# How to select count of each user by time period (e.g., hour)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.2

How do I write a Postgresql query to find the counts for users by hour?

Table:

```
date                 name
-------------------  ----
2015-01-01 23:11:11  John
2015-02-02 23:22:22  John
2015-02-02 23:00:00  Mary
2015-02-02 23:59:59  Mary
2015-03-03 00:33:33  Mary
```

Desired output:

```
        hour         | name    | count
---------------------+---------+-------
 2015-01-01 23:00:00 | John    |     1
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | Mary    |     2
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | John    |     1
 2015-03-03 00:00:00 | Mary    |     1
```

I tried this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a50d4/2:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO my_table (date, name) VALUES ('2015-01-01 23:11:11', 'John');
INSERT INTO my_table (date, name) VALUES ('2015-02-02 23:22:22', 'John');
INSERT INTO my_table (date, name) VALUES ('2015-02-02 23:00:00', 'Mary');
INSERT INTO my_table (date, name) VALUES ('2015-02-02 23:59:59', 'Mary');
INSERT INTO my_table (date, name) VALUES ('2015-03-03 00:33:33', 'Mary');

SELECT DISTINCT
       date_trunc('hour', "date") AS hour,
       name,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', "date")) AS count
FROM my_table
ORDER BY hour, count;
```

but it gives me:

```
 hour                | name | count |
---------------------|------|-------|
 2015-01-01 23:00:00 | John |     1 |
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | Mary |     3 |
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | John |     3 |
 2015-03-03 00:00:00 | Mary |     1 |
```

Similar:

- [Select distinct users group by time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050847/select-distinct-users-group-by-time-range/16052114#16052114)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute)

Comment: You only need a window function for a *running* count (then you also need `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause to make it meaningful). For a plain count per hour, a plain aggregate function does the job.

Comment: Please do not edit my answer as you did twice and I rolled back both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with the window functions, you need to add "name" into your list like this:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a50d4/51

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   date_trunc('hour', "date") AS "hour",
   name,
   count(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name, date_trunc('hour', "date")) AS "cnt"
FROM my_table
ORDER BY hour, cnt DESC
```

Comment: hahaha you edited your answer exactly to me except column name :D

Comment: I didn't notice that. I've removed that part since it was duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    date_trunc('hour', "date") as "hour",
    name,
    count(*) as "count"
from my_table
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 3 desc;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a50d4/62

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a50d4/57

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,
                date_trunc('hour', date) as hour,
                count(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name, hour
ORDER BY hour, count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       date_trunc('hour', "date") AS hour,
       name,
       count(*) as tcount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY  hour,name
ORDER BY  hour, count(*) Desc
```

**Output:**

```
        hour         | name    | count
---------------------+---------+-------
 2015-01-01 23:00:00 | John    |     1
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | Mary    |     2
 2015-02-02 23:00:00 | John    |     1
 2015-03-03 00:00:00 | Mary    |     1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a50d4/34)